# Adjustable (circuit-)tikzpicture as standalone with interchangeable nodes/pathes (in TexStudio)

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuitikz, coordinates

Im looking for a smooth way to adjust an existing `circuitikz` as standalone to create closely related outputs with varying content. Like switching through different settings for my scheme.
E.g. the ampere meters as seen below need to be replaced by simple connecting lines i.e. removed, the labels/anchors are supposed to be replaced by IDs, colours of several objects interchanged, etc.

I imagine myself creating the general circuit layout with all the necessary coordinates, objects, etc. defined and switching between different output scenarios e.g. "w/ or w/o measurements", "IDs only", "energy path (not)visible", "different energy paths" (alpha, beta,...).

I have used layers so far (for the aforementioned "energy path") but that doesnt really do any more since I cant/dont want to just activate new layers which e.g. blank out existing meters with white space and add another line. I feel like there might be packages which can help me achieve something in the direction Im going. But I havnt found anything sufficient so far.

Different comments useable within the script inside TexStudio would be optimal since Im  still going to change the initial circuit layout several times in the future, but do not want to clear out the meters or change colours by hand every time Im adding or deleting new sections. Hopefully ppl understand what Im after. The following MWE probably helps. Let me know if additional clarification is needed.

Edit: Added less complicated MWE without energy paths. Exemplary I would like to achieve replacing every `to[ameter, ...]` with a simple line `--` or replace the block texts with alternative text by using one command/switch. See exemplary pictures.

```latex
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}

\usepackage[%
%   compatibility,
%   european,%
    siunitx,%
    RPvoltages,%
]{circuitikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepackage{standalone}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, shapes, arrows, backgrounds, chains, fit, calc }

\colorlet{vmeter}{black!30!green}
\colorlet{ameter}{black!20!red}
\tikzset{%
    block/.style = {rectangle, draw, text centered, inner sep=.2cm},%
    vmeter/.style = {rmeter, color=vmeter, t=\tiny{\si{\volt}}},%
    ameter/.style = {rmeter, color=ameter, t=\tiny{\si{\ampere}}},%
    mground/.style= {ground, scale=.6},%
    label distance=2ex,%
    marker/.style={orange, line width=4mm, rounded corners,},% opacity=0.3, line cap=round},
}
\ctikzset{instruments/scale=.3}
\begin{document}

\newcommand{\tdesc}[1]{\tiny{\texttt{#1}}}
\begin{circuitikz}
    % custom coordinates
    \coordinate (v VMeter2GND) at (0,-1);
    \coordinate (h VMeter2GND) at (-.5,0);
    % blocks
    \node [block] (pvgen) {PV GEN};
    \node [block] (load) at (1,-7) {Load};
    % coordinates
    \coordinate (pvbus mid) at ($(pvgen.south)+(0,-1)$);
    % bus
    \draw [ultra thick] (pvbus mid)++(-2,0) coordinate(pvbus west) node[anchor=south west](pvbus desc){PV} -- ++(4,0) coordinate(pvbus east);
    \draw [ultra thick] (pvbus west) ++(0,-4) coordinate(acbus west) node[anchor=south west](acbus desc){AC} -- (acbus west -| pvbus east) coordinate(acbus east);
    % coordinates
    \coordinate (pvbus mid) at ($ (pvbus west) !.5! (pvbus east) $);
    % dcac
    \draw ($(pvbus mid) !.2! (pvbus mid |- acbus west) $) coordinate(pvdcac in) to[sdcac] ($(pvbus mid) !.8! (pvbus mid |- acbus west) $) coordinate(pvdcac out);
    % addtional main wiring
    \draw (pvgen.south) -- (pvbus mid);
%   % voltage measurement
    \draw (pvbus west) ++ ($-1*(h VMeter2GND)$)  coordinate(vpv) to[vmeter, l=\tdesc{V PV}] ++ (v VMeter2GND) node[mground]{};
    \draw (acbus west) ++ ($-1*(h VMeter2GND)$)  coordinate(vac) to[vmeter, l=\tdesc{V AC}] ++(v VMeter2GND) node[mground]{};
    % current measurement
    \draw (pvbus mid) to[ameter, label=\tdesc{A PV IN}] ++(v VMeter2GND) -- (pvdcac in);
    \draw (pvdcac out |- acbus west) coordinate (acbus pvdcac in) to[ameter, a=\tdesc{A PV OUT}] (pvdcac out);
    \draw (load.north |- acbus west) coordinate (acbus load in) to[ameter, a=\tdesc{A LOAD}] (load.north);

\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

Schematics w/ measurement instruments
[image: Schematics w/ measurement instruments]
Schematics w/o measurement instruments
[image: Schematics w/o measurement instruments]

Comment: The only thing I can think of us to use things like \newif or \ifcase with \newcount.

Comment: Hm I figured this might be non-trivial. Would you reckon this might be achievable with console tex command without IDE? But I guess the command line as well as tex syntax will get quite complicated?
Thanks so far anyway.

Comment: For what do you want this? I do several things like that for beamer presentations with overlays. Simply you draw to alternative circuits fenced with an `\ifthenelse`. If you try to post a smaller MWE I can see if I can help...

Comment: I will post a simpler MWE. Well I need to display my schematics with different informations. E.g. with or without measurments (hence switiching between simple connecting lines and ampere meters) or displaying different text as the labels.
Im thinking of something like defining a special object that displays a straight path or e.g. ampere meter based on like 1 command at the beginning of the standalone/tikzpicture.

Comment: I added a different MWE with 2 images, that hopefully explain what Id like to achieve. Sorry for the delay, s/th came up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am still not sure if I understand the question, and I am still thinking that the example is anything but minimal --- but probably it's my fault, and the two things are connected.

Let's see if this helps... I am supposing you are not doing this to have elements appearing and disappearing in presentation with `beamer`, in which case you can easily use overlays for that.

For example, suppose I want (or not) a meter following a flag. I can do it quite literally [with the package `ifthen`](https://ctan.org/pkg/ifthen):

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[european, RPvoltages, straightvoltages]{circuitikz}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\newboolean{showmeters}
\newcommand{\mybigsubcircuit}{%
    \draw (0,0) to[R=$R$, *-] ++(3,0) coordinate(a);
    \ifthenelse{\boolean{showmeters}}
    {\draw (a) to[rmeterwa, color=red] ++(2,0) coordinate(b);}
    {\draw (a) to[short] ++(2,0) coordinate(b);}
    \draw (b) to[short, -o] ++(1,0);
}
\begin{document}

\setboolean{showmeters}{false}
\begin{circuitikz}
    \mybigsubcircuit
\end{circuitikz}

\setboolean{showmeters}{true}
\begin{circuitikz}
    \mybigsubcircuit
\end{circuitikz}

\end{document}
```

[image]

(This is *minimal* --- you can use numbers or strings or whatever `ifthen` provides for comparisons and branches).

Comment: I suppose you are right. I could have make it way easier. The problem is I dont need just one thing do be dis- or enabled like single nodes (e.g. ampere meter) but also different labels, textstyles and or transparent thick paths. But this seems like a very difficult thing to put in a question and maybe I should have just stuck with a simple example as yours, covering one. 
But Anyway, cheers for the effort. It generally looks like something I could use for either of those cases and I will check out tmrw with my code.